# Angular: Cannot read property of undefined when using nested properties in interface

Tags: angular, typescript

i'm facing problems using nested property interface.

```
//Food Interface (food.interface.ts)//

export interface Food {
 name: string;
 quantity?: string;
 description?: string;
 nutrients?: {
  calories?: number;
  protein?: number;
  carbs?: number;
  fats?: number;
 };
}
```

food.component.html

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Calories" [(ngModel)]="food.nutrients.calories" name="foodCalories" #calories="ngModel">
```

food.component.ts

```
import {Food} from '../../models/food/food.interface';
export class FoodComponent {

 food = {} as Food;

 constructor() {}

}
```

When i use the first level properties it is working perfectly fine, but when i use the nutrients.(any property) it is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `food` is initialized with `{}`. Means that the properties have their default values. Because you also have a property name `nutrients` which is **optional**, it's default value is `undefined`. You need to initialize it as well like

```
food = { nutrients: {} } as Food;
```

Comment: ```as``` is an operator? I try to look for information but I don't know how to find it, since I don't really understand how it works or what it does.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare **`nutrients`** as empty object so that it wont be undefined when you access on template

```
food = {} as Food;
this.food.nutrients = {};
```

Comment: ```as``` is an operator? I try to look for information but I don't know how to find it, since I don't really understand how it works or what it does.